# Listing data from Active Directory via SharePoint user control

Tags: c#, sharepoint, user-controls, active-directory

I need to create user control for SharePoint to list all users from Active Directory, their names, surnames, telephone numbers, email addresses. I don't have idea how to start, what do I need to do to acomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/pl-PL/sharepointdevelopment/thread/25349f8f-502d-4013-a6ca-ead998140ef4

this one is one of the example